# Creating a new profile for Channels creates one for Stack Overflow automatically

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I created a <s>sock puppet</s> different account just to test out the channels, but it instead [created a new account on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9464244/testing-it).

Is there a way to just create new accounts on the channel and *not* on Stack Overflow?